# Why can't my Google Sheets Query recognize formula results as numbers?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have a formula one one sheet that calculates the difference between the current date (Using the today function) that corresponds to when a repair was requested - this column gives me how many days have passed since the request was made. In a separate sheet, I want to query the requests that are beyond 14 days old but less than 22 days. I write the query as:

Select A,B,C,D,G Where J>14 and J<22

but the cell just displays "N/A". But if I rewrite the code with single quotes on the 14 and 22 as:

Select A,B,C,D,G Where J>'14' and J<'22'

It returns repair requests that are two days old. This tells me that it recognizes the formula results as Strings even if I already set the format to Number.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Share a link to your sheet or a copy of it. Without being able to see the problem in context, there is little the volunteer contributors here can do to assess the problem or suggest a solution.

Comment: @ErikTyler I'm sorry I wasn't able to get back to your comment. I've been busy. Thanks so much though for taking the time. I recently found out about the VALUE() function for spreadsheets, I tried it out and it solved my problem. This confirmed my suspicion that Google Sheets didn't recognize my calculation results as Numbers.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. You can achieve the same thing by multiplying a string-number by 1 or by adding 0 — any math operation that wouldn't change the value. So for instance, you could use `VALUE(A2)` or `A2*1` or `A2+0`; any of these would signal to Sheets that you mean the data in A2 to be a number (if possible).

Comment: @ErikTyler thanks! I'll keep this in mind, this def will become handy

Answer (score 0):

To anyone wondering, I was able to fix this issue by using the VALUE() function (which works for both Google Sheets and MS Excel) which converts any string to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

if J column are dates try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({A:G, DAY(J:J)}
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col7 
  where Col8 > 14 
    and Col8 < 22")
```